# Ruby on Rails - ToastUI Viewer do not show when emailing PDF using wicked_pdf

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-7, wicked-pdf, toast-ui-editor

I am using Rails 7.0.6 and Ruby 3.1.4p223

I am trying to email a PDF file to the user with a ToastUI markdown viewer.

`email.pdf.erb`

```
<head>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap" %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui-editor/latest/tui-editor.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui-editor/latest/tui-editor-contents.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.48.4/codemirror.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/github.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://uicdn.toast.com/tui-editor/latest/tui-editor-Editor-full.js"></script>
</head>

<page>
  <div class="markdownViewSection" data-content="<%= @department.description %>"></div>
</page>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if($('.markdownViewSection').length > 0){
      $.each($('.markdownViewSection'), function(index, el) {

        // Ensure tui.Editor is defined and loaded correctly
        if (typeof tui.Editor.factory === "function") {
          try {
            var editor = new tui.Editor.factory({
              el: el,
              initialEditType: 'wysiwyg',
              previewStyle: 'vertical',
              exts: ['table'],
              initialValue: $(el).data('content')
            });

            // Continue with any further code related to the editor
          } catch (error) {
            $(".markdownViewSection").text(error);
          }
        } else {
          $(".markdownViewSection").text(typeof tui.Editor);
        }

      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

After trying to open the email using letter_opener, I am getting tui.Editor.factory is **undefined** and tui.Editor is an **object**.

In my Department Edit page, tui.editor is a **function**. I use the same script and it's rendering bullet points and tables.

I am assuming there is something wrong in loading tui-editor-full cdn.

Can anyone please help on how to properly load ToastUI into a pdf.erb file?

I tried loading the toastUI by cdn and it still didn't work. I got an object instead of a function.